# ASP.NET performance counter logging, reporting tool

Tags: asp.net, perfmon, performancecounter

I have been looking for a solution to allow us to monitor our web servers performance counters over an asp.net website.

Is there an existing tool that I can make use of to accomplish this or will I need to roll my own?

The only solution I have found online is the use of perfmon to connect to the remote server, this I need to avoid.

The only criteria we need is the ability to select or configure what counter are used and a web interface to few these counters at a later date. We need a historical record or the servers performance.

We are using asp.net websites on IIS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perfmon remotely is the standard way to monitor performance counters remotely. This is done by sys admins across the globe.

Why do you need to avoid this?

However, your will need to roll out your own. I had done this in the past (users who could not figure out perfmon...).

In terms of historical data - you will need to poll the performance counters yourself and record the data somehow (database, flatfiles etc).

You can also setup a website to display current values, control and configure performance counters - the accounts the site runs under will required sufficient permissions, however.

Comment: Its one of the clients requirements that the monitoring is done via a website. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ian - fair enough, though probably the kind of detail you would want to include in your question. Answer updated.